# "non-zero exit status" error when trying to installing ICEWS R package

Tags: r, windows-10, failed-installation

I am asking the question after going through Q&As that mentioned similar problems and trying the solutions suggested without any success.

I am trying to install the 'icews' R package from github on a brand new Dell XPS15, OS windows 10, and the latest version of Rstudio. I tried to install the packages via the 'devtools', 'remotes' and 'githubinstall' packages. I have verified that Rtools is installed (it didn't solve the problem). The following error message was recieved:

No matter which one I use, the installation fails with the error message:

```
During startup - Warning message:
   Setting LC_CTYPE= failed 
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEHNrQX\remotes38706fd9500e\andybega-icews-417ac82/DESCRIPTION' ... 
-  preparing 'icews':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'icews_0.2.0.9003.tar.gz'

Installing package into 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.6'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Error: (converted from warning) Setting LC_CTYPE= failed
Execution halted
Error: Failed to install 'icews' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package 'C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpEHNrQX/file3870683f63a2/icews_0.2.0.9003.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions you would be willing to give me regarding possible solutions.

Comment: The "had non-zero exit status" is not the informative part of the error message. It would be helpful if you edit your question to include **all** the output after `install_github("andybega/icews")`

Comment: The information you need is in the part that says `WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed. Please download and install Rtools 3.5 from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.` You'll need to install `Rtools` first from the URL given

Comment: Thanks! I ensured that Rtools is installed using find_rtools(). However it didn't solve the problem. I have edited the question with the current error message.

Comment: The core problem seemed to be  `Error: (converted from warning) Setting LC_CTYPE= failed Execution halted`. The following solved it: '"Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.1252")
Sys.setenv(LANG="en_US.UTF-8")
Sys.setenv(LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8") '

Comment: Glad to hear you solved your problem! If you were able to solve your problem, Stack Overflow actually encourages answering your own question (and accepting that solution when you can).

Comment: Thanks! Just added my answer

Answer (score 0):

After going through a lot of answers on Stack Overflow and solving several secondary problems, the core problem turned to be:

```
Error: (converted from warning) Setting LC_CTYPE= failed Execution halted
```

The following solution, also found on Stack Overflow turned out to solve it:

```
ys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.1252") Sys.setenv(LANG="en_US.UTF-8") Sys.setenv(LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8")
```

I'm still not sure what is the meaning of the core problem and what the solution actually did.